# How to recieve JSON Post request to contoroller?

Tags: .net

When I try recieve Post json request, Postman gives an error message
[Image (Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ORDx.png)

Another one example [Second image (Click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpnMX.png)

Why is life so painful?

Comment: You have to post your json too, since it seems it has a bug

Comment: I create absolutly new API project, but the problem remains. When I send Http Post with any json, Postman gives an error message [Screenshot] https://i.imgur.com/ad3BL7A.png

Comment: Try to remove Console.WriteLine(); it is really strange to see it inside of API. And add [frombody] - see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

you have a bug in your json. This is why it can not be parced. if you need some help, post your json or try to use an online service, this one https://jsonlint.com/ for example.

I just tested your last code in a postman. I only added [frombody] to an action. Selected body=>raw=>json options in postman

```
 public ActionResult Test([FromBody] JToken jToken)
  {
            return Ok(jToken.ToString());
  }
```

output status OK 200

```
{
  "field": "Hello World"
}
```